# Create lmdb for multi label classification

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, multilabel-classification

I am trying to create 2 lmdbs. One for my images one for my labels. I want to determine the angle of a picture, to do so I am trying to estimate the horizontal and the vertical angle. I have classes like: 0-10 degree horizontal 10-20 degree horiozntal and so on. And the same for vertical angles. Now I do not know how to create the label db as in how the labels have to be formatted in the lmdb.
I have a `.txt` list file with: `/path/pic.png 1 32` entries where `1` means 10-20 degree and `32` means 320-330 degrees. 
My code looks like this:

```
for line in fileinput.input(data):
    entries = re.split(' ', line.strip())
    images.append(entries[0])
    labels.append(entries[1:])
.... 
for in_idx, (image, label) in enumerate(inputs):
    im = cv2.imread(image)
    im = im[:,:,::-1]
    im = im.transpose((2,0,1))

    im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
    print im_dat

    images_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), im_dat.SerializeToString())

    label = np.array(label).astype(int).reshape(1, 1, len(label))

    label_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(label)
    labels_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), label_dat.SerializeToString())
```

This however seems not to be correct since I got following error when trying to train the network:

> Check failed: outer_num_ * inner_num_ == bottom[1]->count() (10 vs. 20) Number of labels must match number of predictions; e.g., if softmax axis == 1 and prediction shape is (N, C, H, W), label count (number of labels) must be N*H*W, with integer values in {0, 1, ..., C-1}.

My data layer looks like this:

```
name: "LearnAngle"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "images"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 256
    mean_file: "/path/mean_train.binaryproto"
  }
  data_param {
    source: "path/train2_images_lmdb"
    batch_size: 10
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data_label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "labels"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "path/train2_labels_lmdb"
    batch_size: 10
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
```

My last layers looks like

```
layer {
  name: "fc8"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
    decay_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
    decay_mult: 0
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 36
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}

layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc8"
  bottom: "labels"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: Can you also upload the data layer?

Comment: Done! @DaleSong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: your `top: "labels"` in the 2nd `data` layer contains 2 kind of labels for the horizontal and vertical angle, while you just used 1 `SoftmaxWithLoss` layer for the labels.

In fact, to train 2 classification tasks in one network, you can create 2 `lmdb` databases for the 2 tasks' labels respectivly, and use 2 `data` layers to parse them to 2 `SoftmaxWithLoss` layers. Like what's below:

Code for creating `lmdb` for 2-task classifications:

```
for line in fileinput.input(data):
    entries = re.split(' ', line.strip())
    images.append(entries[0])
    horizontal_labels.append(entries[1])
    vertical_labels.append(entries[2])

...
for in_idx, (image, label) in enumerate(inputs):
    im = cv2.imread(image)
    im = im[:,:,::-1]
    im = im.transpose((2,0,1))

    im_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(im)
    print im_dat

    images_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), im_dat.SerializeToString())
    horizontal_label = [label[0]]
    vertical_label = [label[1]]

    horizontal_label = np.array(horizontal_label).astype(int).reshape(1, 1, 1)
    vertical_label = np.array(vertical_label).astype(int).reshape(1, 1, 1)

    horizontal_label_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(horizontal_label)
    vertical_label_dat = caffe.io.array_to_datum(vertical_label)

    horizontal_labels_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), horizontal_label_dat.SerializeToString())
    vertical_labels_txn.put('{:0>10d}'.format(in_idx), vertical_label_dat.SerializeToString())
```

train_val.prototxt:

```
name: "LearnAngle"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Data"
  top: "images"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  ...
}
layer {
  name: "horizontal_label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "horizontal_label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "path/horizontal_labels_lmdb" #created using above python code
    ...
  }
}
layer {
  name: "vertical_label"
  type: "Data"
  top: "vertical_label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  data_param {
    source: "path/vertical_labels_lmdb" #created using above python code
    ...
  }
}
... #follow layers
# branch for horizontal label classification
layer {
  name: "fc_horizon"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc_horizon"
  ...
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 36
    ...
  }
}

layer {
  name: "loss_horizon"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc_horizon"
  bottom: "horizontal_label"
  top: "loss_horizon"
}
# branch for vertical label classification
layer {
  name: "fc_vertical"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc_vertical"
  ...
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 36
    ...
  }
}

layer {
  name: "loss_vertical"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc_vertical"
  bottom: "vertical_label"
  top: "loss_vertical"
}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your python code! Where do the label[0] and label[1] come from? since you have renamed it earlier?

Comment: Isn't `label` a list?  See this line `for in_idx, (image, label) in enumerate(inputs):` @thigi

Comment: Yeah but you have changed the label name to horizontal and vertical labels. I assume you can zip (images, veritcal labels, horizontal) labels to input?

Comment: @thigi That's also OK.

Comment: Would you recommend to add an accuracy layer? Or isnt that needed?

Comment: 'Accuracy' layer is ok for TEST. For deployment you can use a 'Argmax' layer. @thigi

Comment: Ok, does it improve the training? How would you call the deep learning method we have used here? multi-label classification? or multi-class classification?

Comment: Maybe it'll. I would call it multi_class classification but multilabel also make sense @thigi

Comment: Ok thank you so much! Well, I am getting a loss of 3.8 which isnt decreasing. Looks like I have to refine sth! But I think the data is the problem! However, if it would not be the fault of the data what could be possibilities for the bad result?

Comment: Learning rate, try smaller one may help @thigi

Comment: Yeah, do you have any other helpful tips for me? I really appreciate your help!! Thank you so much!!! I might come back to you in the future since I want to do depth estimation!

Comment: Please post  a new question if you will have. @thigi

Comment: One short question! What do you prefer: Tensorflow, caffe or Torch?

Comment: Any is ok. Trying a bit  more is not a bad thing @thigi

Comment: Yeah, so everything is possible with all the three frameworks? Well, my problem is to understand the basics, since I am new to this topic, do you have any reading suggestions for caffe or in genreal?

Comment: Mostly it satisfies just try and thinking @thigi

Comment: Yeah most of the time I know what I want , but I do not know how like in this case! And when I try to find solutions there is no documentation or anything wich helps me. For example my next step is to estimate the depth of an image which means: I have an imgae as data and a depth image as "label data" and the output has to be an image. But I have no clue how to do this! But I will ask this in a further question!

Comment: Don't be afraid just try and read the book <Deep Learning> and read more papers and ask and try ok? @thigi

Comment: Ok, where can i find that book?

Comment: Well, Google is a good tool. Some knowledge on machine learning is also neeed. @thigi

Comment: Yeah I have no prior knowledge to it! That is the problem! I am trying to get knowledge tho! I just do not know where to get it from!

Comment: Just search there are many. Sorry please don't chat if you have any problems please post it as a question! All you need is time be patient  @thigi

Comment: Just posted a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246526/caffe-depth-estimation

Comment: Why not correct? What do you mean by mapping from image to label?@thigi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126813/discussion-between-thigi-and-dale-song).